# Ant zip task will lost symbolic link?

Tags: ant, zip

I used the below task to compress the folder to a zip file. But I found that the symbolic links in the folder lost when I unzipped the zip file.

```
<zip destfile="${file.path}">
             <fileset dir="/tmp"/>
</zip>
```

For instance, previously, the file look like below.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 xxxx xxxx        25 Mar 15 21:02 libboost_atomic.so -> libboost_atomic.so.1.57.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xxxx xxxx      9135 Feb  8 04:46 libboost_atomic.so.1.57.0
```

After I compressed the folder using Ant and unzipped it, it look like below.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxx xxxx      9135 Feb  8 04:46 libboost_atomic.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxx xxxx      9135 Feb  8 04:46 libboost_atomic.so.1.57.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of the built-in zip command, try the using the exec and use

```
 <exec executable="zip">
    <arg value="--symlinks"/>
    <arg value="-r"/>
    <arg value="${file.path}"/>
    <arg value="tmp"/>
  </exec>
```

I tried the command line equivalent on mac and worked for me, please let me know on what system are you trying this.

Note, this requires you to have a 'zip' executable in your path (which I assume you do)

Answer (score 1):

The zip format itself doesn't really support symbolic links in a portable way (and Ant doesn't support any of the not-so-portable options). Neither does Ant's `tar` task.